# Java Couchbase Unsupported type for JsonArray

Tags: java, spring-data, couchbase

I get an exception while I am trying to get objects from CouchBase. I use Spring Data Repository to query data. I save data to CouchBase without any exceptions. I need to query data by `dataTime` which should be in range `dateBefore` and `dateAfter`.
I have such Java Object:

```
@Document
public class DataObject{

    @Id
    @Field
    private String dataId;
    @Field
    private boolean isEnabled;
    @Field
    private BigDecimal price;
    @Field
    private LocalDateTime dataTime;
    @Field
    private Currency currency;

    public DataObject() {
    }

    public DataObject(String dataId, boolean isEnabled, BigDecimal price, Date dataTime, Currency currency) {
        this.dataId = dataId;
        this.dataId = dataId;
        this.price = price;
        this.dataTime = dataTime;
        this.currency = currency;
    }
}
```

I have such repository interface:

```
public interface DataObjectRepository extends CrudRepository<DataObject, String> {

    @Query("#{#n1ql.selectEntity} WHERE dataTime BETWEEN $1 AND $2 AND #{#n1ql.filter}")
    List<DataObject> getDataObjectsBetweenDates(LocalDateTime beforeTime, LocalDateTime afterTime);

}
```

When I run this query I got an exception:

> org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request
>   processing failed; nested exception is
>   java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unsupported type for JsonArray:
>   class java.time.LocalDateTime

I tried to use `Timestamp`, old Date instead `LocalDateTime`, however I got the same exception but with different Class in the message.

I am new to CouchBase, so any help appreciated

Comment: Yes. My first thought was that Couch Does not support LocalDateTime querying, then I tried Timestamp and got:
Unsupported type for JsonArray: class java.sql.Timestamp and also I tried Date and got 
Unsupported type for JsonArray: class java.util.Date

Comment: I don't know why your error thinks you have a JsonArray. Where are you changing things? In the class or just on the N1ql method?

Comment: By the way I copied some query and then modified for my needs. It might be that error in the query

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what `AND #{#n1ql.filter}` is supposed to do, but if you can save data using `LocalDateTime`, I think that class should be converted fine.

Comment: Is it possible that it can save it to DB(converts to JSON object), however it is not possible to query by Date range. Couch should know how to work with LocalDateTime like a Date

Comment: I don't know. Is that what you are seeing? I was only reading the Spring documentation. That's the issue, not CouchbaseServer itself (which does support date queries)

Answer (score 0):

You got this exception, because couchbase java client tries to add your `beforeTime` to parameters array, but can't do this. `LocalDateTime` is not supported type and don't satisfy to this check inside client :

```
public static boolean checkType(Object item) {
    return item == null
        || item instanceof String
        || item instanceof Integer
        || item instanceof Long
        || item instanceof Double
        || item instanceof Boolean
        || item instanceof BigInteger
        || item instanceof BigDecimal
        || item instanceof JsonObject
        || item instanceof JsonArray;
}
```

When you save `LocalDateTime` to couchbase  spring converts it to `Long` :

```
Date.from(source.atZone(systemDefault()).toInstant()).getTime();
```

So, you can also convert your dates with this approach and send `Long` parameters instead of `LocalDateTime`